# Giving private tutoring classes using an iPad Pro and Apple Pencil

Tags: ipad, video, skype

Most of the private tutoring classes I give are done through the internet. I connect a Wacom tablet to my Macbook Pro, open a new Photoshop document, share my screen with my student through Skype and off I go. I am wondering if I could do the same but, instead of the Macbook+Wacom+Photoshop+Skype combo I could use an iPad instead and share my iPad screen with my students.

If that is possible, what video call software could I use? (I know for instance that Skype won't allow a shared screen on an iPad).